# Pandas Dataframe - Renaming of last column doesn't work

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rename

I am having issues with renaming last column of my dataframe. My dataframe has 47 columns and I am able to rename all columns except the last one.

```
data.rename(
{
    "Electricity:Zone:B001 [J](TimeStep)": "strom_verbr_zone",
    "Electricity:Facility [J](TimeStep)": "strom_verbr_ges",
    "B001FEOST:Surface Shading Device Is On Time Fraction [](TimeStep)": "f_verschattung_io",
    "Gas:Facility [J](TimeStep)": "gas_verbr"
}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

After running this Code every column Name changes except the last one. The column "Gas:Facility J" just won't rename. Tried it on other ways as well but without any success until now.
Does anyone have an idea how to make it work or why it doesn't rename?

Comment: Double-check the spelling of your column names

Comment: Try passing a list of the changed names to `data.columns`, it may work but keep the order in mind. Also, it will save a lot of trouble of writing the names.

Comment: @ilyankou thanks for the tip. It had to do with the spelling. There were some whitespaces at the end of the last column name which I didn't recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try:

```
# in the same order as you need
data.columns = ["strom_verbr_zone", "strom_verbr_ges", "f_verschattung_io", "gas_verbr"]
```

Testing renaming the last column in an empty dataframe with the names as provided:

```
# created a blank dataframe with just the headers with given column names
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Electricity:Zone:B001 [J](TimeStep)", 
"Electricity:Facility [J](TimeStep)", 
"B001FEOST:Surface Shading Device Is On Time Fraction [](TimeStep)",
"Gas:Facility [J](TimeStep)" ])

print(df.columns)
```

Output:

```
Index(['Electricity:Zone:B001 [J](TimeStep)',
       'Electricity:Facility [J](TimeStep)',
       'B001FEOST:Surface Shading Device Is On Time Fraction [](TimeStep)',
       'Gas:Facility [J](TimeStep)'],
      dtype='object')
```

.

```
# renamed just the last column
df.rename(
{
    "Gas:Facility [J](TimeStep)": "gas_verbr"
}, axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df.columns)
```

Output after renaming just the last column:

```
Index(['Electricity:Zone:B001 [J](TimeStep)',
       'Electricity:Facility [J](TimeStep)',
       'B001FEOST:Surface Shading Device Is On Time Fraction [](TimeStep)',
       'gas_verbr'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: My dataframe has 47 columns. Is there a way to just change the name of the last column or do I really have to type all 47 columns?

Comment: In that case data.rename() is better. Ideally it should work. As suggested in one of the comments above, can you check for spellings and whitespaces.

Comment: Also, I tried renaming the last column, if the spelling are the same as you have mentioned, then it is working fine for me. Test run results added to my answer

Comment: It really had to do with the spelling. The program where I got the data from seems to add some whitespaces at the end of the last colum name. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

could try:

```
cols = data.columns 

cols[-1] = 'new name'

data.columns = cols
```